# How to sort a tibble by column order? (first column, second column, third...)

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I have a tibble that contains an arbitrary number of columns.
These columns were inserted in order so their index (first, second, ...) is meaningful.

I'm trying to sort the tibble by the first column, then the second column, then the third, and so on.

I'd rather keep using `dplyr::arrange()` to be consistent with my framework, but if it cannot be done I'd gladly accept any solution.

Also, if missing values could be considered last that would be a great plus.

Here is a reproducible example with my expected output and some failed attempts:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
x=as_tibble(mtcars)[1:4] %>% sample_n(5)
x
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  15.2     8  276.   180
#> 2  19.2     8  400    175
#> 3  21.4     6  258    110
#> 4  14.3     8  360    245
#> 5  21       6  160    110

# **** EXPECTED OUTPUTS: ****

arrange(x, mpg, cyl, disp, hp)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  14.3     8  360    245
#> 2  15.2     8  276.   180
#> 3  19.2     8  400    175
#> 4  21       6  160    110
#> 5  21.4     6  258    110
arrange(x, hp, disp, cyl, mpg)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  21       6  160    110
#> 2  21.4     6  258    110
#> 3  19.2     8  400    175
#> 4  15.2     8  276.   180
#> 5  14.3     8  360    245

# **** MY FAILED ATTEMPTS: ****

arrange(x, all_of(colnames(x)))
#> Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
#> * Problem with `mutate()` column `..1`.
#> i `..1 = all_of(colnames(x))`.
#> i `..1` must be size 5 or 1, not 4.
arrange(x, !!all_of(colnames(x)))
#> Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
#> * Problem with `mutate()` column `..1`.
#> i `..1 = <chr>`.
#> i `..1` must be size 5 or 1, not 4.
arrange(x, !!!all_of(names(x)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  15.2     8  276.   180
#> 2  19.2     8  400    175
#> 3  21.4     6  258    110
#> 4  14.3     8  360    245
#> 5  21       6  160    110
do.call(arrange, x, colnames(x))
#> Warning in if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote): the condition has length >
#> 1 and only the first element will be used
#> Error in if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote): argument is not interpretable as logical
do.call(arrange, x, list(colnames(x)))
#> Error in if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote): argument is not interpretable as logical
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `arrange_all` has been deprecated, you can use `across` in `arrange`.

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% arrange(across())

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  14.3     8  360    245
#2  15.2     8  276.   180
#3  19.2     8  400    175
#4  21       6  160    110
#5  21.4     6  258    110
```

For reverse you can do -

```
x %>% arrange(across(.cols = ncol(.):1))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  21       6  160    110
#2  21.4     6  258    110
#3  19.2     8  400    175
#4  15.2     8  276.   180
#5  14.3     8  360    245
```

---

In base R, you can use `do.call` with `order` -

```
#1.
x[do.call(order, x), ]

#2.
x[do.call(order, rev(x)), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# arrange by column left to right:
x %>% arrange(!!!syms(colnames(.)))

# arrange by column right to left:
x %>% arrange(!!!syms(rev(colnames(.))))
```

Output:

```
> x %>% arrange(!!!syms(colnames(.)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  14.3     8  360    245
2  15.2     8  276.   180
3  19.2     8  400    175
4  21       6  160    110
5  21.4     6  258    110
> x %>% arrange(!!!syms(rev(colnames(.))))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6  160    110
2  21.4     6  258    110
3  19.2     8  400    175
4  15.2     8  276.   180
5  14.3     8  360    245
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    arrange(across(everything()))
```

-output

```
 A tibble: 5 x 4
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  14.3     8  360    245
2  15.2     8  276.   180
3  19.2     8  400    175
4  21       6  160    110
5  21.4     6  258    110
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, but how's that different from Ronak's answer?

Comment: It uses `everything()`

Comment: @DanChaltiel you may check yourself, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68617046/revisions) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68645348/revisions). These are only some though

Comment: I suggest you open a meta post about that kind of behavior. That is an obvious side-effect from the point system but this is pretty nasty. However, the hypocrisy might exist between you two but I'm not a part of it so you are being unfair. Moreover, being aggressive with everybody will only get you enemies and rejection, regardless of you being in the right.